# Unable to save content DNNConnect.CKE html editor (DNN)

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7, dnn9

Unable to save and change html editor type from Rich Textbox editor to basic Text Box Editor.
Getting error www.domain/page/ctl/Edit/mid/4267?popUp=true , 403 error
Using DNN 9.8.01,DNNConnect.CKE as html editor

Answer (score 0):

I was running into same error. For me it turned out to be using `"("` and `")"` in the HTML code. Somehow the editor is not allowing to use those anymore. I am still looking for an alternative unfortunately.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29953963)